# OCaml Change Path of Standard Library

Tags: cygwin, ocaml, opam

I have installed OCaml on Windows using the 64-bit graphical installer found [here](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/).

When I run `ocamlc -config` in the Windows command prompt, It tells me that the standard library is located here:

```
standard_library_default: C:/cygwin/home/appveyor/.opam/4.12.0+mingw64c/lib
standard_library: C:/cygwin/home/appveyor/.opam/4.12.0+mingw64c/lib/ocaml
```

However, the `cygwin` directory does not exist at all, and I believe the standard library is actually located in

```
C:\OCaml64\home\MyUser\.opam\4.12.0+mingw64c\lib\ocaml
```

Is there any way to change the path of the standard library?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to override them is there anything that doesn't work? Have you activated opam before that, i.e., used `ocaml-env`, for example to run the cmd.exe you should do, `ocaml-env exec -- cmd.exe`

Comment: @ivg I should've said in my question, the reason that I think that this is is an issue is because whenever I go to compile my program `answers.ml` by running `ocamlc -o answers answers.ml` in the windows command prompt, I get the error message `File "command line", line 1:
Error: Unbound module Stdlib`. I even get this when simply typing `ocaml` in. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the `standard_library_default` as it is stored in the binary, but you can use the `OCAMLLIB` environment variable to override the `standard_library` path.

But most likely you don't need to change it. You should either run your commands in a cygwin terminal and activate your opam using

```
eval $(opam env)
```

Or, if you want to use a windows terminal, like `cmd.exe` you can use the [ocaml-env](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/ocaml-env/) helper for that, e.g.,

```
:: run cmd.exe
ocaml-env exec -- cmd.exe
:: start utop from the 4.03.0-mingw64 switch
ocaml-env exec --switch=4.03.0-mingw64 -- utop.exe
:: run utop inside ConEmu / Notepad
ocaml-env-win --switch=4.04.0-msvc32 -- "C:\\Program Files\\ConEmu\\ConEmu.exe" -run utop.exe
ocaml-env-win -- "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"
```