# Ocaml compile on eclipse using Makefile occurs no file error even if there is

Tags: eclipse, ocaml, mingw

[image]

When I try to compile my project with Makefile, it keeps show error that there is no file `lang.ml` even if there is in same path. It seems that `make.exe` can't totally recognize the file contents in projects.
Maybe there is problem with entering directory `/home/mario/eclipse/assignment/miniML_skel` folder, but I can't find the way how to check or manange the path where `make.exe` actually gone through.
However, the absolute path of project is `C:/OCaml64/home/mario/eclipse/assignment/miniML_skel` and workspace is set as `C:/OCaml64/home/mario/eclipse/assignment`.
I create this project as an `Ocaml Empty Makefile Project` and import contents file from some other folder.

[image]

[image]

Here is paths of preference and project.

Note that if I compile `lang.ml` separately and create `lang.cmo` file, then make process normally detect it and continue.

Comment: You're looking in a wrong direction, read the error message carefully, it says: `"make: ocamlc: No such file or directory"` so it can't find the `ocamlc` executable. Make sure that `ocamlc` is in your PATH, also, you probably need to add `.exe` suffix.

Comment: @ivg Thank you for the solution. After I add ocamlc in PATH, it seems that compiler can go to next step. However, now console says that 'Unbound module Stdlib' and I can't find how to fix it. When I compile on cygwin terminal there was no problem. Should it be also a PATH problem?

Comment: That is strange, could it be possible that you have several OCaml installations on your system? Try running `ocamlc -where` and `ocamlc -version` in Eclipse and Cygwin environments and compare the results. The `-where` option shows where the standard library is supposed to be. And the version should be `4.13.1` on both. Also, as far as I understand OCaIDE (very little), the Paths and Project Paths preference options are not used when you're using the Makefile project.

Comment: Also, we would need more information on how you build the project. Are you using the `Make Project` menu? And what Makefile targets do you have?

Comment: @ivg Yes, I use `Make Project` to build the project which show when I right click my project folder on navigator. Also, As I create cygwin bash through `Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration` and run it, there  when command `ocamlc -configure` the field `standard-library` set as `C:/cygwin/home/appveyor/.opam/4.13.1+mingw64c/lib/ocaml` which doesn't exist.
So it might seems that when I try to build my project using `Make Project` on navigator it parse wrong directory either `standard-library` and `OCAMLLIB` environment variable but still don't know how to configurate it.

Comment: @ivg Additionally, there are no `OCAMLLIB` value when I run cygwin through eclipse, and if I set it as ` C:/OCaml64/home/mario/.opam/4.13.1+mingw64c/lib/ocaml` in `External Tools Configuration -> Environmnet`, it works normally.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, it looks like your OCaml compiler is improperly built. It hardcodes an incorrect path to the toolchain.  You can either install a different distribution of OCaml or try to circumvent the broken OCaml by setting up the OCAMLLIB variable to the correct path, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002426/2625442

Comment: @ivg I solved it by using external tools with cygwin and launch group configuration. Thank you so much for the help. :)